# What do I need for testing a single script in admin

Tags: wp-admin, scripts

I like to test a single script in the wp-admin area.
Do not know what to include at the top of my script.php file for testing including all kind if DB access + Wordpress like $wpdb->get_results, $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_row, etcetera.
Url for testing will be: www.mydomain.coml/wp-admin/script.php

Is there a minimum of files to include so I can run the script like a WP file?

Hope someone of you with more skills then me can give me a solution.
Thanks anyhow.

Comment: What is the purpose of this kind of setup? Why not just run this code in context of WordPress?

Comment: [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) are the easiest for front-end WordPress testing. And for back end, [adding a menu page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and doing necessary things in the callback functions is the easiest way to achieve such functionality.

Comment: I want to test email bounces. Therefor I need WP db access and WP commands to test. I try to test it with only mysqli commands. But that does not work for me. So if you know the includes requirements to test 1 script file within the environment of WP admin, would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're trying to create a custom Admin Page. Instead of adding a file into the admin folder, you can create custom admin pages from your WordPress plugin or theme by using the 'Admin Menu' action.

In short, you will need to add something like the following to your plugin, or your theme's functions.php file.

```
// Create the page
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

// Define the page content 
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

For full details on how to do this, please view the section about Admin Pages on the WordPress Codex.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

I hope that helps!

Comment: #Robin seems fine for me. I will try that.